# When was the setting of Chitty Chitty Bang Bang?

Tags: chitty-chitty-bang-bang

The opening scenes of the 1968 film *Chitty Chitty Bang Bang* have a clear setting: the Grand Prix races of 1906 to 1909. The rest of the film takes place an unspecified amount of time later, when the car that was wrecked at the end of the 1909 race is found by two children and their father. [Wikipedia claims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chitty_Chitty_Bang_Bang) that this main story takes place in "the mid-1910s" but offers no evidence or citation for this claim.

**When does the main story of *Chitty Chitty Bang Bang* take place, and how is this known?**

Comment: The novel makes reference to the M20 (a UK motorway) which wasn't started until 1920

Comment: @Paulie_D.  The M20 opened in 1971, well after the book was written.

Comment: The first part of the [M20 opened in 1960](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M20_motorway#History), but I think @Paulie_D might be thinking of the A20, the first part of which [opened in 1923](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A20_road_(England)#History)

Comment: As I said, the book **specifically** mentions the M20 but perhaps Fleming got that wrong.

Comment: Is there anything to suggest the book is period rather than contemporary?

Comment: @Tetsujin That was my original thought too - I'd kind of assumed it was set in the mid-20th century, long after the 1906-09 races. But as a kid I lacked the historical knowhow to distinguish between one long-past decade and another, and now I see it does make sense to be in the early 20th century. Look at Truly's car, for example, or the fact that long-distance transmission of moving pictures is mentioned as a bizarre novelty.

Answer (score 10):

*Too much for a comment, perhaps not enough solid evidence for an answer…*
I'm trying to do this from memory, I haven't seen the movie in a long time.

In "the mid 1910s" there was a war on, don't you know?

Usually anything in this movie style is set indeterminately 'between the wars' to avoid any political background. This period is often used as a cultural idyll, halcyon days, the time after 'the war to end all wars' - green fields, straw boater hats, cricket on the village green, salmon and cucumber sandwiches, everlasting summers. It's a British [or even just English] folk memory of something that never actually really existed. Because it is such a deeply-seated cultural 'meme' it never really has to be accurate.

In this type of story you can refer back loosely to 'the last war' or earlier, which they do in the fantasy sequence - presumably Vulgaria is a hint at a small non-specific country that was on 'the wrong side' in the last one [60s family movies rarely mentioned a specific country as 'the enemy' though there was often one or more characters wearing a [pickelhauber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pickelhaube), the 'pointy helmet', if they wanted to indirectly refer to the Great War]. Vulgaria's rulers are mocked up like something from the old Austro-Hungarian Empire. There are also broad strokes, design-wise, of Dickens meets Grimm, in Austria.  Because this entire sequence is fantasy, we can't use it for reliable dating.

Grandpa is an 'old soldier' - presumably from the Boer War or maybe even Burma or the British Raj, but I recall him in khakis & a pith hat at one point, which would make that post-1880. If he was 20 in 1880, he'd be 65 in 1925.

I thought perhaps to use [information on the car](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chitty_Chitty_Bang_Bang_(car)) for dating, but that was unsuccessful. Fleming's car was 'built in 1920' but the movie car 'raced from '06-'09' so we can't use that. The actual car[s] used in the movie were completely custom designed, apparently on a Ford chassis, but that gives us no real hint.

Trying to date the other cars recognisable gives us a [1909 Humber](https://www.beaulieu.co.uk/news/chitty-chitty-bang-bang-and-truly-scrumptious-1909-humber-return-to-iconic-film-location-in-oxfordshire/) driven by Truly Scrumptious, which could place it before WWI, as could some of the clothes she wore. I'm no expert on historical costume, though.
There's a [1912 Austro-Daimler](https://www.hampshireattractions.co.uk/rare-lord-scrumptious-car-joins-beaulieus-chitty-exhibition/) owned by Lord Scrumptious and used in Grandpa's kidnap.
There's an outlier in a [1925 Rolls Royce](https://www.getsurrey.co.uk/news/surrey-news/gallery/chitty-chitty-bang-bang-cars-19717377) identified from some footage of the filming of the races at Box Hill; but it's said that these cars were not really meant to be identifiable & were all replicas. The Rolls itself was re-configured to look like a racing car, so it might just be that it 'looked right from a distance'. [I can't get their video to load, btw].

I don't think I can come to a real conclusion, unfortunately. It might be 1912/13 just before WWI, or it might be early to mid 20s, between the wars.
Best guess is only based on Grandpa's assumed age, which would put it in the 20s. [Lionel Jeffries is actually slightly younger than Dick van Dyke, so his in-universe age is only ever going to be a guess.]

Comment: *"I haven't seen the movie in a long time"* - you know what to do to fix that :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor - ordinarily, yes… but though I love a lot of the cinematography, the art design & the brilliant Rowland Emett 'things' - I don't actually like that kind of mid-60s musical… they grate a bit ;))

Comment: I agree with 1920s. The breakfast machines scene has a blade-style switch on the wall, this is considerably cruder than the "modern" style toggle switches that became common when most of the UK got mains electricity in the 1930s. I'd suggest that it connected to a generator powered by the mill sails, which would be fairly accessible technology post- "Great War" but not really before, the same applies to what look like Tungsram incandescent bulbs. So: post-1920, pre-1935, I call '27.

Comment: It's a shame the recent DVD birthday special didn't have more from this movie. I think the only performance was "Hushabye Mountain". Although they did have him sitting in a replica of the car.